# google-services.json file is missing

Tags: android, json, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I placed **google-services.json** file in my **/app** module directory. Still getting this error!

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Is there an updated solution to this problem? Please, anyone help me.

Comment: did you checked that the package names are equal?

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happens with me.

> Remove the google-services.json file from your project .Set up for the API which you want in your project(Maps,FCM,etc).then place your google-services.json file in your root directory.Rebuild and clean.
>
> Hope this will help you.